# Giving access to parts of a github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on Github for which I would like to give access to a freelancer.

I can't give them access to the entire codebase for security reasons, but I would like to be able to merge their changes from the sections that I do give them access to.

If I create a fork and remove the restricted files then it still has the history available, so that doesn't really work.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove the files from the history and publish it as-is, then consider using `git filter-branch`, which will let you narrow a project down to just some components of the original complete repository.

Putting the code you want them to see into a submodule would be the other way to go, and give them access to just the submodule.